# How can I import users in contact list through hook or API in sugarcrm?

Tags: joomla, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to integrate users of my Joomla site into sugarcrm panel. I'm using SuiteCRM Version 7.7.6 [Sugar Version 6.5.24 (Build 509)] and trying to import csv file of users into contact list of sugarcrm through hook.
Means I want to build functionality for auto integration in between Joomla and Sugarcrm site. When a new user register on Joomla site, they should be auto added in the contact list of crm panel.

Is there any possible way to implement this integration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution to integrate records in a particular module of sugarcrm through Rest API.

- Create php file anywhere outside your CRM project directory and write API code as given below.
- Need to set site URL of sugarcrm and configure admin username and password in API.
- After that, set module name in which you want to add data.
- Adjust your data in given array format.
- Now just hit the file URL on browser where you placed this API.
- Data will be successfully added in the required module.

**API Code:**

```
    $url = "http://{site_url}/service/v4_1/rest.php";
    $username = "admin";
    $password = "password";
    //function to make cURL request
    function call($method, $parameters, $url)
    {
        ob_start();
        $curl_reque**strong text**st = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($parameters);
        $post = array(
             "method" => $method,
             "input_type" => "JSON",
             "response_type" => "JSON",
             "rest_data" => $jsonEncodedData
        );
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
        curl_close($curl_request);
        $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
        $response = json_decode($result[1]);
        ob_end_flush();
        return $response;
    }
    //login -------------------------------------------- 
    $login_parameters = array(
         "user_auth" => array(
              "user_name" => $username,
              "password" => md5($password),
              "version" => "1"
         ),
         "application_name" => "RestTest",
         "name_value_list" => array(),
    );
    $login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);
    /*
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($login_result);
    echo "</pre>";
    */
    //get session id
    $session_id = $login_result->id;
    //create contacts ------------------------------------ 
    $set_entries_parameters = array(
         //session id
         "session" => $session_id,
         //The name of the module from which to retrieve records.
         "module_name" => "Contacts",
         //Record attributes
         "name_value_list" => array(
             array(
                //to update a record, you will nee to pass in a record id as commented below
                //array("name" => "id", "value" => "912e58c0-73e9-9cb6-c84e-4ff34d62620e"),
                array("name" => "first_name", "value" => "John"),
                array("name" => "last_name", "value" => "Smith"),
             ),
             array(
                //to update a record, you will nee to pass in a record id as commented below
                //array("name" => "id", "value" => "99d6ddfd-7d52-d45b-eba8-4ff34d684964"),
                array("name" => "first_name", "value" => "Jane"),
                array("name" => "last_name", "value" => "Doe"),
             ),
         ),
    );
    $set_entries_result = call("set_entries", $set_entries_parameters, $url);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($set_entries_result);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Click here for more details:
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/REST/PHP/Creating_or_Updating_Multiple_Records/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be possible, although not practicable to do in a hook.

If you need to import a CSV more than once, implementing a scheduler job for the import might be a good idea.

However you could actually not use CSV at all and let Joomla or an intermediate script push the data to sugar in real-time or a time interval of your choice using the REST API of your CRM.